# How do you unspesify a variable in js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Ok, I am going to make this a bit more clear:
Is there any way you can do this:

`message.channel.send(plan_(args[2])`

If `args[2]` would be: `Example`

Then it would message the channel the value of the variable called `plan_Example`

Comment: hi, if you share some code it would help understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is take the **3rd argument** and use it to get a variable, you could easily do this using the following line:

```js
message.channel.send(`${plan_}${args[2]}`)
```

Comment: It'd be more helpful and clearer to read if you edit any extra information into your question

Comment: That was my fault, I fixed my answer now

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way do define a variable this way?
`var plan_(args[2]) = args[3]`

Comment: I don't think so, also accept my answer if it solved your question to let others know it worked

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Click the tick mark under the arrows next to my answer